# Searching mongodb with mongoose inside AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs, mongoose, mean-stack

Hello everyone am trying to search (query) the mongodb using mongoose in my AngularJS app. Am looking to have specific element. Can you help ? Any suggestion would make me advance. I need the general idea. Also I am new to mean

here is my angular code :

```
var app = angular.module('chirpApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']).run(function($rootScope, $http) {
  $rootScope.authenticated = false;
  $rootScope.current_user = '';

  $rootScope.signout = function(){
      $http.get('auth/signout');
      $rootScope.authenticated = false;
      $rootScope.current_user = '';
  };
});

app.config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
    //the timeline display
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'main.html',
      controller: 'mainController'
    })
    //the login display
    .when('/login', {
      templateUrl: 'login.html',
      controller: 'authController'
    })
    //the signup display
    .when('/register', {
      templateUrl: 'register.html',
      controller: 'authController'
    })
  //search
    .when('/search', {
      templateUrl: 'search.html',
      controller: 'searchController'
    });
});

app.factory('postService', function($resource){
  return $resource('/api/posts/:id');
});

app.controller('mainController', function(postService, $scope, $rootScope){
  $scope.posts = postService.query();
  $scope.newPost = {created_by: '', text: '', created_at: ''};

  $scope.post = function() {
    $scope.newPost.created_by = $rootScope.current_user;
    $scope.newPost.created_at = Date.now();
    postService.save($scope.newPost, function(){
      $scope.posts = postService.query();
      $scope.newPost = {created_by: '', text: '', created_at: ''};
    });
  };


});
app.controller('searchController', function(postService, $scope, $rootScope){
  $scope.posts = [];
  $scope.posts = postService.get(text:"1223");
  $scope.tiks=[];
  $scope.newPost = {created_by: '', text: '', created_at: ''};

   $scope.post = function() {
    $scope.newPost.created_by = $rootScope.current_user;
    $scope.newPost.created_at = Date.now();
    postService.save($scope.newPost, function(){
      $scope.posts = postService.query();
      $scope.newPost = {created_by: '', text: '', created_at: ''};
    });
  };
});

app.controller('authController', function($scope, $http, $rootScope, $location){
  $scope.user = {username: '', password: ''};
  $scope.error_message = '';

  $scope.login = function(){
    $http.post('/auth/login', $scope.user).success(function(data){
      if(data.state == 'success'){
        $rootScope.authenticated = true;
        $rootScope.current_user = data.user.username;
        $location.path('/');
      }
      else{
        $scope.error_message = data.message;
      }
    });
  };

  $scope.register = function(){
    $http.post('/auth/signup', $scope.user).success(function(data){
      if(data.state == 'success'){
        $rootScope.authenticated = true;
        $rootScope.current_user = data.user.username;
        $location.path('/');
      }
      else{
        $scope.error_message = data.message;
      }
    });
  };
});
```

in the searchController am trying to query a specific post with text 123.

Here is my schema :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },       
    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    text: String
});

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String, //hash created from password
    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
})


mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);
mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Comment: Please show us some code of what you have already tried. Also worth noting that AngularJS is a client app framework, so it's not possible to directly query a database using Angular.

Comment: 10q for your reply I have edited the question do u have some ideas ?

Comment: What error/unexpected behaviour are you getting?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list and angular.js:78 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module chirpApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'chirpApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: So the problem seems to be as simple as a missing `(` somewhere in your code. The editor you are using to code should help you on that.